# Why do i not get the output I expect in this simple JS if statement

Tags: javascript

I am a JS beginner. Just read a couple of beginner books. I am now taking an online course and even though I thought I knew if statements this bit of code doesn't seem to run right.

Here is the simple code that is taken directly from the course teaching materials:

```
let stationery = "pen";
if (stationery == "pen" || "pencil") { 
    console.log("You have enough stationery to write the exam.");
}
else {
    console.log("You do not have sufficient stationery to write the exam.");
}
```

On the face of it it seems ok. When I see console.log the output say: You have enough stationery to write the exam.

However, if I change the stationery variable to something else like "chalk" and rerun the if statement, the console.log result still says: You have enough stationery to write the exam.

I would expect the final else statement to kick in and show: You do not have sufficient stationery to write the exam.

This is so early on in the course that I am almost embarrassed to ask. What am I missing?
The beginner books I read were before let and used var. Is it anything to do with this that is confusing my beginner's understanding?

I think this could be something to do with "truthy" values in the if statement conditionals but I don't get it.

Thanks.

Comment: your if statement is wrong. you check variable with every condition. try `if (stationery == "pen" || stationery == "pencil")`

Comment: either you repeat the variable name or use `includes` with an array `if( ["pen","pencil"].includes(stationery)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong, it always will return a true value, because `"pencil"` is a truthy value, [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,type%20coercion%20in%20Boolean%20contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,type%20coercion%20in%20Boolean%20contexts).

```js
let stationery = "pen";
if (stationery == "pen" || "pencil") { 
    console.log('this is always true')
}
```

Maybe this is the logic you are looking for:

```js
let stationery = "pen";
if (stationery == "pen" || stationery ==  "pencil") { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yikes. Thanks for your reply. I haven't learned things like "truthy" values yet. The course materials are wrong then. I will study this, but I have to say I'm now even more confused.